# vue and laravel combination, do i have an extra router?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am new in this area and i want to start my first project with vue for front end and laravel for back end

I learned that both laravel and vue have a built in router dose that mean I am going to have an extra router in my project or do they serve in different ways?

Comment: They serve in different ways. Laravel has a route for the actual API endpoints, Vue has a route for the pages themselves.

Comment: The question is too unspecific. It's unknown what result you need. You may want to check Inertia